# conversion of bash to tcsh script for sed and and seq loop

Tags: bash, tcsh

I have been trying to use a bash script for a tcsh shell. And I do not know how to convert the following bash script for tcsh. I use the following bash script to repalce a character in a file and print out 100 of files from that as the following:

```
for i in $(seq 0 101); 
do 
    sed s/X/$(($i*40+4505))/g < file.txt > input$(($i*40+4505)).txt; 
done
```

How to convert the above for a tcsh?

Comment: That's not a good way to do it in bash either -- `seq` is neither part of bash nor part of the POSIX standard, so it isn't guaranteed to be available or to have any particular behavior when it is. See http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/counting

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `tcsh` also isn't part of POSIX, so I guess he's not restricting himself to POSIX systems.

Comment: @Barmar , I agree. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tcsh equivalent of `for variable in list` is `foreach variable ( list )`. `tcsh` doesn't have `$()` for command substitution, it uses backticks. And it doesn't have `$(())` for arithmetic, it uses `@` (which is similar to `let` in `bash`).

So:

```
foreach i ( `seq 0 101` )
    @ val = $i * 40 + 4505
    sed s/X/$val/g < file.txt > input$val.txt
end
```

Comment: You can use `@` for arithmetic: `@ val = $i * 40 + 4505`. Don't need to use `expr`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij It's been about 20 years since I did much tcsh programming. Forgot about that.